# Не отрисовывается куб OpenGL

Tags: opengl

У меня почему-то не отрисовывается куб, пытался отдебажить, но ошибок никаких не выдает. Не понимаю в чем может быть проблема.
Ниже код конструктора и метода, который занимается отрисовкой.

```
    Cube::Cube()
{
    GLfloat tmp[] = {
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,      1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Верхний правый угол красный
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,      0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, // Нижний правый угол желтый
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,      0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Нижний левый угол зеленый
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,      0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, // Верхний левый угол голубой
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,      0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Верхний правый дальний угол синий
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,      0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, // Нижний правый дальний угол фиолетовый
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,      1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Нижний левый дальний угол красный
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,      0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f  // Верхний левый дальний угол зеленый
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        this->vertices[i] = tmp[i];

    GLuint _indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3,   // 1й треугольник
        1, 2, 3,   // 2й треугольник
        4, 5, 6,   // 3й треугольник
        4, 6, 7,   // 4й треугольник
        1, 5, 2,   // 5й треугольник
        5, 6, 2,   // 6й треугольник
        0, 4, 7,   // 7й треугольник
        0, 3, 7,   // 8й треугольник
        6, 7, 2,   // 9й треугольник
        3, 7, 2,   // 10й треугольник
        4, 1, 5,   // 11й треугольник
        0, 4, 1    // 12й треугольник
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        this->indices[i] = _indices[i];

    this->vertexSahder.readShader("Shaders/Triangle/vertexShader.vert");
    this->vertexSahder.createShader();
    this->fragmentShader.readShader("Shaders/Triangle/color.frag");
    this->fragmentShader.createShader();

    this->shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(this->shaderProgram, this->vertexSahder.shader);
    glAttachShader(this->shaderProgram, this->fragmentShader.shader);
    glLinkProgram(this->shaderProgram);

    GLint success;
    GLchar info[512];

    glGetProgramiv(this->shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        log("ERROR::LINK_PROGRAMM");
        glGetProgramInfoLog(this->shaderProgram, 512, nullptr, info);
        cout << info;
    }

    glDeleteShader(this->vertexSahder.shader);
    glDeleteShader(this->fragmentShader.shader);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(this->vertices), this->vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &this->EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(this->indices), this->indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    this->rotateUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(this->shaderProgram, "rotateTransform");
}
```

Также, метод рисования

```
void Cube::draw()
{
    glUseProgram(this->shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Вершинный шейдер:

```
#version 450 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

out vec3 vertColor;

uniform mat4 rotateTransform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0f);
    vertColor = vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Фрагментный шейдер:

```
#version 450 core
in vec3 vertColor;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(vertColor, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: [Минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) в студию.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы рисуете куб в единичном пространстве,без матриц камеры и вида? Также, вполне вероятно,что вы рисуете все треугольники нормалями наружу, т.о. т.к. они одностороние - вы их просто не видите.

Comment: Дело в том, что есть другая программа, она рисует тот же куб, но ещё и вращает его. Там это работает, вершины и индексы взяты оттуда, единственное, что я сделал, расписал логику в классы. И да, без камеры и тд. Но дело в том, что в примере, который мне скинули тоже нет камеры

Comment: Запишите чем-нибудь лог вызовов OpenGL функций (RenderDoc вроде умеет такое). Сравните логи оригинальной программы и вашей.

Comment: Еще вариант: Попробуйте проверять `glGetError()` после каждого вызова.